# How to make a complex heading with two lines like this?

Tags: header-footer

I made a very complex in MS word, and I want to move it into LaTeX, how to it? It is composed of two lines, one is big font, another is small font. Can we only use fancyhdr to draw a two-line header? Or we need to use tikz?

I've written some code but i don't know how to put them into the header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\LARGE
\uuline{\textbf{Experiment Report}}
\end{center}
\centerline{\rule{16cm}{0.4pt}}

\begin{center}
\uline{XX} Department \qquad number:\uline{\quad} \qquad name:\uline{XXX} \qquad date:21
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: latex printed like this]
latex printed like this
[image: the ideal header i want like in MS word]
the ideal header i want such as one in MS word (it appear on the header)

Comment: For future questions, please consider providing a so-called MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. The `-1` is *not* from me but I *assume* it is because of the missing MWE.

Comment: So you mean i should add more details?

Comment: It is a *general recommendation* that shows what you have tried so far, which document class you are using, etc.

Comment: ok, i will try.

Comment: Is my edition ok?

Comment: I do not see any code in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130390/discussion-between-jiajie-and-dr-manuel-kuehner).

Comment: You can use the fancyhdr package, you can create a LaTeX pagestyle, you can even use `\AddToHook{shipout/background}` and add stuff anywhere on the page.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601292/header-image-overlap-header-line for example.

Comment: Regarding your added code: You did not read/follow the link I provided, since the code is not compatible. One should be able to copy and paste your code and compile it without modifications. Please re-read the MWE questions.

Comment: Is this for a single page, or multiple pages?

Comment: this is for one page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how to get a two-line header (with the 2nd line below the rule) but here is a start using the famous [`fancyhdr` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fancyhdr) for related questions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

%% Head
% Left
\lhead{}
% Center
\chead{\Large Experiment Report}
% Right
\rhead{Score: \makebox[10mm][l]{\hrulefill}}

%% Foot
% Left
\lfoot{Param A: \makebox[10mm][l]{\hrulefill} Param B: \makebox[10mm][l]{\hrulefill} Param C: \makebox[10mm][l]{\hrulefill} Param D: \makebox[10mm][l]{\hrulefill}}
% Center
\cfoot{}
% Right
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes， but i want these four parameters in the header too, is there any way out?

Comment: @jiajie As I said, I do not know how to achieve it. Maybe you can deviate from the MS Word template but I cannot decide that obviously.

Comment: ok, thanks for your work!

Comment: In header you can insert `tabular` environment where in the first row you insert "experiment record" and in the second other information.

Comment: ok let my try , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried tablular and it's available for me.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhead[C]{
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\uuline{\LARGE{ Experiment Report}}} &  \\
     \uline{one} Departmet & Para B:\uline{Name } & C:\uline{No.111} & Date: \uline{Oct.xx}
\end{tabular}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

[image: latex screenshot]